# Segue from TableViewController to another TableViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uistoryboardsegue

Using storyboards I have a table view controller with a list of rows. When a row is selected, I want to pass the data associated with that row across to another table view controller which is embedded within an UINavigationController.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"EditJob"])
    {
        NewJobsTableViewController *newJobsTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        Jobs *job = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        newJobsTableViewController.jobDetails = job;

    }
}
```

On the last line within the prepareForSegue method I am getting the following error:

[UINavigationController setJobDetails:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x83a7780
2012-11-11 08:50:25.335 My Trades[40612:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setJobDetails:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x83a7780'

jobDetails is declared in the newJobsTableViewController as:

```
@interface NewJobsTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,      NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
    Jobs *_jobDetails;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) Jobs *jobDetails;
```

I am not sure why it's causing this error.

Comment: Did you try to log your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you set up your storyboard wrong. That second tableViewController shouldn't be embedded in its own navigation controller. Just set up a push segue from your first tableViewController to the second -- the second will automatically be embedded in the same navigation controller as the first one.

The reason for the error, I think, is because the destination view controller is actually the navigation controller that you embedded the second view controller in.  This line doesn't do what you expect it to do:

```
 NewJobsTableViewController *newJobsTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
```

Even though you're setting the return value of destinationViewController to your class, it will return whatever it actually is -- I'm betting that if you log the class of newJobsTableViewController, it will actually come back as UINavigationController.

Comment: How would you retrieve NewJobsTableViewController then?

Comment: @Stas, just don't embed that second table view controller in its own navigation controller, then that line will retrieve NewJobsTableViewController.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to re-use NewJobsTableViewController for adding and editing data. So I had an initial segue to add new data, but then I also added another segue to edit data as well and this is where it all went wrong. I simply copied/pasted the NewJobsTableViewController scene onto the story board and then redirected the "edit" segue to the copy, but both reference the same class file.